# How to share ownership of a directory between two users

Tags: node.js, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, nvm

I've created an EC2 instance and built a Jenkins Server

```
//my current folder
pwd
> /var/lib/

// permissions of jenkins
ls -la
> drwxr-xr-x 10 jenkins jenkins 4096 Dec 27 02:24 jenkins
> ...
```

I've also installed node via nvm

```
//by default installs in home directory under ec2-user
pwd
> /home/ec2-user

// the permissions get set to ec2-user
ls -la
> drwxrwxr-x 266 ec2-user ec2-user 20480 Dec 27 02:42 .npm
> drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 27 02:33 .nvm
> ...
```

Jenkins needs access to .nvm && .npm folders otherwise the builds will fail when I try to npm install.

**Question:**
How do I share ownership properly so that user: `jenkins`  can use `ec2-user` > `.npm` and `.nvm` directories ?

**OR**

How can I install .nvm under the jenkins name and group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the user jenkins to ec2-user group:

```
usermod -G ec2-user -a jenkins
```

Comment: I've tried this under sudo su -.  how can I validate it when through?  since there was zero feed back.  (trying out the job as a wayto validay but i'm just curious if theres another way)

Comment: not sure what you mean. 'groups jenkins' will print the groups where the user jenkins belongs